# Hue connect to hiveserver2 via http

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I'm trying to connect Hue to Hiveserver2 via http. I use Hue 3.7 (github version) and Hive 0.13.1.

This is my hive-site.xml configuration:

```
<property>
  <name>hive.server2.transport.mode</name>
  <value>http</value>
  <description>Server transport mode. "binary" or "http".</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.port</name>
  <value>10001</value>
  <description>Port number when in HTTP mode.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.path</name>
  <value>cliservice</value>
  <description>Path component of URL endpoint when in HTTP mode.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.min.worker.threads</name>
  <value>5</value>
  <description>Minimum number of worker threads when in HTTP mode.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.max.worker.threads</name>
  <value>500</value>
  <description>Maximum number of worker threads when in HTTP mode.</description>
</property>
```

I used this instruction:
https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/hue-user/ghdFwSuUDfE
but it doesn't work. When I start Hue and click Metastore Table  I get an error message:

```
TSocket read 0 bytes
```

This is traceback:

```
[15/Jan/2015 11:53:32 +0100] middleware   INFO     Processing exception: TSocket read 0 bytes (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException('TSocket read 0 bytes',): Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hue_3.7/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.6.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/hue_3.7/apps/metastore/src/metastore/views.py", line 108, in show_tables
    databases = db.get_databases()
  File "/opt/hue_3.7/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/dbms.py", line 123, in get_databases
    return self.client.get_databases()
  File "/opt/hue_3.7/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/hive_server2_lib.py", line 813, in get_databases
    return [table[col] for table in self._client.get_databases()]
  File "/opt/hue_3.7/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/hive_server2_lib.py", line 480, in get_databases
    res = self.call(self._client.GetSchemas, req)
  File "/opt/hue_3.7/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/hive_server2_lib.py", line 443, in call
    session = self.open_session(self.user)
  File "/opt/hue_3.7/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/server/hive_server2_lib.py", line 417, in open_session
    res = self._client.OpenSession(req)
  File "/opt/hue_3.7/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/thrift_util.py", line 340, in wrapper
    raise StructuredThriftTransportException(e, error_code=502)
StructuredThriftTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes (code THRIFTTRANSPORT): TTransportException('TSocket read 0 bytes',)
```

Check Configuration of Hue returns:

```
Hive Editor     The application won't work without a running HiveServer2.
```

but I can connect to Hiveserver2 via Beeline.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported yet but will come in Hue 3.8: https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-2534